# Pakistani passport validity for traveling from UAE to Pakistan and back

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, pakistani-citizens, dxb

I want to know that i am currently doing job in Dubai, UAE. and i am from Pakistan. My passport is getting expire on 11th of April 2017 and today is 15th of March 2017. I want to know that can i travel to Pakistan if i want to go on 1st week of April 2017 with the minimum validation of my passport.?

If yes then in how many days i can come back to Dubai, UAE with the same passport or do i have to renew my passport first within the Pakistan and then travel..

Plus what will happen if i don't come back..?

Answer (score 4):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

For [Pakistan](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=pk&DE=pk&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX)

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid **on arrival**.

For [Dubai](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=pk&DE=ae&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=ae&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
>     residents of the United Arab Emirates must be valid **on
>     arrival.**

So you can use your current passport if it's valid when you arrive in Pakistan and when you return to Dubai. If it expires while you're in Pakistan, you have to renew it before returning to Dubai